# Swipe without actually swiping in iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is it possible to make a view move either to the left or right in the iPad, when I tap on a button, instead of actually swiping on the view.

This can be seen in the iPad when I'm in the screen after the search screen, and I install an app, the screens move to the left by itself and the app sits in the right place and starts installing.

Any suggestion will help.

Comment: What kind of view are you using?

Comment: you should accept answers or add new comments if the answer didnt help you, Vittal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home screen is actually a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. So it just moves to the next page (with `scrollRectToVisible`) if a new app is installed. So if you want to have something like that, I guess you have to implement a paging `UIScrollView`. Just search for that and you will find a lot of good tutorials.

Some further resources:

- [`UIScrollView` reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)
- [A paging `UIScrollView` tutorial](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/)